# MODx Relative Links Broken

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I was having a lot of trouble getting relative links working in MODx. As soon as I made a container and put some pages one level above the root, nothing was linking correctly. Lots of missing images and broken links.

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE: This fix apparently will break all links linking to content identifiers.**

I fixed it by putting the following at the top of the web template:

```
<base href="[[++site_url]]" />
```

You have to use that. If you hardcode it, it will screw up depending on which protocol you use, http or https.

Comment: Sorry, but this really isn't an answer to this problem.  All links linking to content identifiers will all break because of this.

Comment: Damn, well thanks for the input. I'll give that disclaimer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

StingyB's answer is correct. This tag should be in the head section of all MODX templates:

```
`<base href="[[++site_url]]" />`
```

Note that if you have multiple front-end contexts, the placeholder should be uncached:

```
`<base href="[[!++site_url]]" />`
```

Also, it must be a short tag. This will not work:

```
`<base href="[[!++site_url]]"></base>`
```

I'm not sure where comment about "breaking all links linking to content identifiers" is coming from. These tags are standard in all MODX installs.